# What shape is this?

Tags: polyhedra

im doing a question that involves a shape with 8 faces, 10 vertices and 16 edges. Can anyone enlighten me as to what this shape is called?
Many Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me that the shape is unique given only this information.

Comment: @Qiaochu:  I believe it is unique.  It takes a lot cases to prove this though.  There are only a couple of possible degree sequences, and only a couple of possible choices for the sequences of faces, and eventually we eliminate all but the degree sequence 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5 and the possibility that all the faces are squares.  I wonder if there is a slicker way?

Comment: I am going to leave my previous comment, but Dan Moores answer definitely shows it is completely wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Additionally, any polyhedron represented at [Professor Steven Dutch's Enumeration of Polyhedra page](https://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/symmetry/polynum0.htm) could also be the shape you're looking for:

Comment: This seems quite definitive.

Answer (score 3):

The [tetragonal trapezohedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TetragonalTrapezohedron.html) seems to fit your bill.

Answer (score 1):

This paper, that enumerates and shows plane 3-connected graphs for the convex polyhedra with 4 to 8 faces, may be of interest: Federico, P. J. Polyhedra with 4 to 8 faces. Geometriae Dedicata 3 (1974/75), 469–481.

Answer (score 1):

It is called an octahedron.

Any polyhedron with eight faces is an octahedron. Unfortunately there are 76 distinct graphs corresponding to polyhedra with the amount of faces and vertices you require, so it is not possible to assign your shape a more specific name.

Please note that even after you restricted your search to a specific graph, all the possible spatial embeddings of such a graph into a polyhedron would result in different names (consider the cube and the truncated square pyramid for instance).

Please also note that Steven Dutch's list - at the time I am writing this post - is not completely accurate, since it contains 77 distinct graphs.